# NameError: global name 'send_from_directory' is not defined

Tags: python, flask

I am working with Flask and trying to serve a file for the user to download.

My code looks something like this:

```
@app.route('/downloads/<string:yt_id>')
def download_file(yt_id):

    def hooks(data):
        if data['status'] == 'finished':
            filename = data['filename']

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
        'progress_hooks': [hooks],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+yt_id])


    return send_from_directory(".",
                               filename,
                               as_attachment=True)
```

I guess the only relevant part of the above code is this:

```
    return send_from_directory(".",
                               filename,
                               as_attachment=True)
```

And this is the error message that I'm getting:

```
NameError: global name 'send_from_directory' is not defined
```

I have looked at several examples of how people are using `send_from_directory` and I don't see much difference with what I am doing. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to import it from flask ... It should be...

```
from flask import send_from_directory
```